# I have similar question with archive log cleanup

Tags: postgresql, archive, postgresql-9.6

Presently in master postgres.conf it says like this
`archive_command = 'cp "%p" "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/archive/%f"'`

In Standby postgres.conf:

```
# - Archiving -

archive_mode = on               # enables archiving; off, on, or always
#archive_command = '/bin/true'                          # (change requires restart)
archive_command = 'cp "%p" "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/archive/%f"'                # command to use to archive a logfile segment
                                # placeholders: %p = path of file to archive
                                #               %f = file name only
                                # e.g. 'test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'
#archive_timeout = 0            # force a logfile segment switch after this
                                # number of seconds; 0 disables
```

In Standby recovery.conf:

```
postgres@e142pu-mam-db1:~$ cat /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/recovery.conf
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.37.76.107 port=5432 user=replication password='
trigger_file = '/var/tmp/standby.trig'
restore_command = 'cp "%p" "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/archive/%f"'
```

Somehow I've got a feeling that I havent configured it correctly. Kindly share your recommendation

Comment: logs are keep growing more than the size of the database, somehow I need help to perform archivecleanup in better way that doesn't harm database

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to cleanup the archivelog both in master and standby in harmless way

Comment: Based on which condition? When do you want to remove archived WALs?

Comment: Looks to me like you have configured Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR). It is one of the 3 main ways to make backups in Postgres. If you have a feeling it is not working as expected, could you, please, share with us what are the reasons you think so? At the glance looks like correct configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `archive_mode` is just 'on', not 'always', the `archive_command` on the standby doesn't do anything (unless and until it gets promoted).

Your `restore_command` doesn't make any sense.  The order of arguments would have to be reversed in order for it to have a hope to work.  Apparently your standby is driven completely off of streaming, and doesn't actually use any log shipping.

If the only reason you have a WAL archive is for log shipping and you aren't even using it for that, then clean up can be very simple, just delete it.